# Permutations of two groups of people

Tags: permutations

When question is "What is the number of ways to create a group of 5 from 17 girls and 20 boys when you have to select at least 3 girls

I needs a simple explanation why it is that
$$
{17\choose3}  {20\choose2} + {17\choose 4}  {20 \choose 1} + {17 \choose 5}
$$
(3 girls with 2 boys ... All girls)
Which is the correct answer and I completely understand the logic

VS
$$
{17 \choose 3} { 34 \choose 2}
$$
(3 girls and random 2 from the remaining 34)
Which is incorrect but I don't understand why it give a different number that the first

Comment: The second one is incorrect because it over-counts: If you picked a,b,c first and then d,e, that gives you the same set as picking a,b,d and then c,e etc..

Comment: And the over counting is not uniform: GGGBB combos are ok in your second method, but GGGGB's are over-counted by a factor of $4$, and GGGGG's by a factor of $10$ -- so fixing up the over-count means splitting up the types as done the first solution, anyway.